# What did God mean when He said to Moses, "I have made thee a god to Pharaoh"?

Tags: exegesis, old-testament, exodus, moses

Perhaps I'm not seeing the meaning behind the translation, but while reading the KJV Exodus, I'm confused by chapter 7 verse 1, which reads:

> "And the Lord said unto Moses, See, I have made thee a god to Pharaoh: and Aaron thy brother shall be thy prophet."

The verse throws me off. I'm sure that God isn't meaning that Moses is literally God. But I thought Moses was the prophet, and Aaron was just a priest under Moses (the prophet). Why would God use this wording, calling Moses "a God"?

Comment: It is not for me to say, exactly, but this might be better posted on [Stack Exchange -Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions) as it is asking for the precise meaning of the Hebrew word behind the translation 'god'.

Comment: The Bible uses the term ***god*** and not the term ***God*** the difference between the two terms is that use of the Capitol ***G*** indicates the eternal God while the use of the lower case ***g*** indicates a false god. The actual meaning of this is to indicate that Moses was given power over Pharaoh.

Comment: @BYE But why does scripture call Moses a 'false' god ? is perhaps the question in the mind of the OP. Why not just call him a 'lord' ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a better fit at [Biblical HermeneuticsSE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: Is it possible to simply transfer this question to Biblical Hermeneutics?  Or does that have to be done by the OP, David?

Comment: The KJV was very fussy about trying to make each word of the original manuscripts translate to a single word in English. More modern translations, without that restriction, render the verse as "I have made you like God to Pharaoh", which gives a pretty clear meaning.

Comment: The key is in the phrase unto pharaoh. Pharaoh was an Egyptian they had a lot of gods  being a god unto pharaoh did not equate with Moses being almighty God.

Comment: @ Nigel The comment from Kris should answer your question about use of the word god in relation to Pharaoh. Moses would now be equal to many other gods that pharaoh was obliged to obey.

Answer (score 1):

Found a useful thought on the page https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2004206#h=23:0-24:0, which notes:

> How was Moses made “God to Pharaoh”? Moses was given divine power and authority over Pharaoh. Hence, there was no need to be afraid of that king.

Highlighted here on another page https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2002564#h=27:0-28:0
 is the following idea:

> Aaron served as a prophet, not in the sense of foretelling future events, but by becoming Moses’ spokesman, or mouthpiece.

Consider that the Pharaoh was himself seen as a god, and that Moses acted in behalf of the "God of gods", who "removes kings and sets up kings" (Daniel 2:21,47). It must have been a fearful thing to be at the Pharaoh's mercy, as the Egyptians would probably have obeyed the Pharaoh without any questions asked. As consequence, it may have been the first time for someone to speak against the Pharaoh at all, not to mention the bold and open manner in which it was to happen. No wonder then that Moses could do with all the reassurance he could get!

Comment: The first link is not working

Comment: Sorry, must have accidentally added a comma in the middle.  Has been corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

@David ~ William Ford published his doctoral thesis as an academic book, called: "God, Moses + Pharaoh" ~ what he told us in an extramural short course was that God was reminding Moses that he was to be God's Priestly and Oracular intermediary between Moses and Himself; and also that, given that Pharaoh's whole culture was governed by many gods, and that Pharaoh and his people regarded Pharaoh himself as a god, Pharaoh would already be ready to engage with Moses, as Moses' dramatically demonstrated God's power, speaking for a/the God of great power, as if Moses himself was that God. And of course you require a more academic response such as you could find in Wm Ford's tome.